# Get same PHP session ID for both html and php files

Tags: php, html

I have two files:
html
php

where html file is calling the php file to do something.

Now i would like to get the PHP session ID (php code) into both my html file as well as my php file.

I would like to know how would I do so so that both html file and php file have the same PHP session ID.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand the question

Comment: don't grasp what you mean - sorry...

Comment: What do you mean by section ID? Is this a variable you've declared in the PHP file?

Comment: PHP cannot work on HTML files.. or you are asking something like server side includes?

Comment: PHP session ID is what i mean sorry

Comment: you can't, you need both files with .php extension and use `session_start();` on the very top

Comment: Why using a php and html file at once? What about php only? You then have no troubles using sessions...

Comment: does session_start() return the same value for both files?

Comment: and also there   must not be any  space before <?php session_start() ?> otherwise you will get the waring

Comment: how do i get the session_start() id? how do i use a variable to store it?

Comment: Would those two session_start() id be the same for both php files? As well, how would you store that data?

Comment: session_id() - http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-id.php for session ID. You can't have sessions in HTML. Make it a PHP file.

Comment: HTML is static so it can NOT use session ID directly, if it is requested by the same client that requests php pages it will be sent within the same session.
@thedom There is no reason to use php (or any scripting pages) for static content. It will only force the server to evaluate every page before serving it to the client

Comment: Refer the reply,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458556/php-sessions-with-html

Thank you........!

Comment: Refer the reply,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458556/php-sessions-with-html
Thank you.

Comment: @GermannArlington as you see, it is not static ;-)... the session id is needed which is dynamic content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't have PHP sessions in HTML files. Best to just change the HTML file to a PHP file.

As mentioned in the comments - make sure you start the session at very top of the file before any spaces before the opening php tags.

To retrieve the session ID use php function session_id() but if the both files are on same domain you just need to call session_start at the very top and it'll just use same session across.

**EDIT**

To answer your qs in comments below -
Yes, a PHP file can just have HTML code but no PHP code at all or add PHP where required. e.g.

Myfile.php

```
<html>
<head> ... </head>
<body>
<h1>some title</h1>
......
......
<a href="#">Go to next page (<?php echo $_GET['next_page']; ?>)</a>
......
</body>
</html
```

so you just open and close php tags where you needed php stuff to go.

To print session ID - just use  somewhere in the HTML of PHP file.

Yes, session_id() will give you the same session ID in php2 file - again, make sure you call session_start function at the very top in the php2 file too.

Comment: if a php file include html, do i do <?php session_id?> to get the id value inside html?

Comment: @RyanFung: almost... ``<?php echo(session_id()); ?>``

Comment: one more question: lets say i call php start session in my first file in php1 file, if i call session id() function in php2 file, does it give me the same number if they both are under the same domain name?

Comment: Answered your ques in the Edit.

Comment: I have the following code in php1:
<?php echo(session_id()); $a = session_id()?>
php2:
<?php echo(session_id()); $a = session_id()?>
Does those 2 a have the same value?

Comment: IT IS NOT WORKING STILLLLLL:(

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to your apache configuration, or a simple .htaccess file, you can tell Apache to handle php code inside of an .html file. You can do this by creating an .htaccess file (remember the . (dot) as the first character in that filename) on the document root of the site (probably public_html/) and putting this into it:

```
# Add this to public_html/.htaccess file
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .html
AddHandler application/x-httpd-php .htm
```

You should be able to reload the html page and your PHP code will run great.

Comment: is it where i put my index.html in?

Comment: i can't create a file start with a .