# Why php to html conversion isn't working?

Tags: php, html, session

I used this tutorial from http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php to learn about sessions in php. The code for page1 and page2 works fine. I want the code to be able to work in html so I edited the php and saved them as two new files.

page1.html

```
 <html>
 Welcome to page #1
<?php
session_start();
echo 'setting variables';
$_SESSION['username'] = 'User1234';
$_SESSION['password']   = 'SecretPassword';
?>

<br /><a href="page2.html">page 2</a>

</html>
```

page2.html

```
<html>
<?php
// page2.php

session_start();
?>
Welcome to page #2
<br />
Username: <?php echo $_SESSION['username']; >
<br/>
 Password: 
 <?php echo $_SESSION['password'] ?> <br/>

 <br /><a href="page1.html">page 1</a>
</html>
```

Where is the error occurring that causes page2.html to return this?

```
Welcome to page #2 
Username: 
Password: 

page 1
```

**Edit*********
Fixed it by adding a .htaccess file that allows me to use EventHandler

Comment: Maybe your HTML files are not being processed as PHP code. Is your server configured to process `.html` files as PHP? If not, you might try renaming the files to `.php`.

Comment: In page 2, you're creating a new session just before your `Welcome to page #2` line.

Comment: If you didn't add anything to your `.htaccess` file to tell it to run `.html` as PHP then it will fail. Using `AddHandler / AddType etc. etc.` will make it go. Google that.

Comment: to add to @showdev, .HTML files are usually not set to be processed by PHP. You need to use .PHP or add `AddType application/x-httpd-php .html` in .htaccess

Comment: `session_start()` should also go before any direct (HTML) output

Comment: As Phil stated above, not doing so will result in a `headers already sent...` because you have `<html>` on top of `<?php`

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP sessions with HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458556/php-sessions-with-html)

Comment: @Fred-ii- The OP probably has output buffering enabled (he says it works for PHP files) but relying on that is like relying on `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, ie a bad idea

Comment: Just too many things happening/not happening in this question/code @Phil let the OP battle with this, I have no more energy to spend on questions like this TBH. Just like VCR's, "too many moving parts".

Answer (score 1):

You should change the extension of your files to `.php` so that  PHP will recognise and interpret them as PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

Any file with php in it needs to have the .php extension instead of .html.  Also, if you're running your own web server (like Apache or similar) make sure you have PHP installed on your machine so the server can interpret PHP.

TLDR:

Change the filenames to .php and the href links to .php .